# Find clusters from a 2 column file

Tags: perl

I have the following problem, I have a file which sorted like it:

```
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
6 7
6 8
9 1
```

Each number represent a "node" of the network. The left node is connected with right node and if they are connected they belong to the same "cluster".

I want to find the number of "cluster" made by those numbers and the cluster composition, which in this case should give the output:

```
cluster[1]=(1,2,3,4,5,9)
cluster[2]=(6,7,8)
```

I thought that it could useful to give a label to each number and each time I find a neighbour of this number or a neighbour of the neighbour it takes the same label ( which then would be the the "n-th" number in the cluster vector `cluster[n]` ) and if there is a number that doesn t belong to any past cluster, then it takes a new label etc.., but I don t know how to reproduce this idea in a code... Any help?

Comment: I think, that it can be done by yourself :) you take next connection, find for each number their cluster connection and merge clusters ;)

Comment: What you are looking for is also known as `Connected Components` in graph theory. You can find lots of ways to solve it online.

Comment: [Try this module: Graph](https://metacpan.org/module/Graph)

Comment: Here is an [example](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=727154) using Graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, you should use [Graph](http://search.cpan.org/). You are looking for the connected components of an undirected graph.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Graph::Undirected;
my $g = Graph::Undirected->new(unionfind => 1);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    last unless $line =~ /\A ([0-9]+) \s+ ([0-9]+) \s+ \z/x;
    $g->add_edge($1, $2);
}

my @cc = sort { @$b <=> @$a }
         map { [ sort @$_ ] } $g->connected_components;

printf "[%s]\n", join(', ', @$_) for @cc;

__DATA__
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
6 7
6 8
9 1
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I am trying to use your code and try to write the output on a file; for this aim I wrote under the line `use Graph::Undirected;` the code `my $file2 = 'cluster.dat';` and `open my $fg, ">", $file or die "Cannot open $file2: $!";` and edited the printf line as `printf $fg "[%s]\n", join(', ', @$_) for @cc;` for little files it works out well, but when I use a huge dataset it writes, in the file, lines as `7455, 7456, 7457, 7458, 7590[%s]` do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

```
my @node_links = (
    {a => 1, b => 2},
    {a => 1, b => 3},
);

my %clusters;

for my $node_link (@node_links) {
    $clusters{ $node_link->{a} } ||= {};
    $clusters{ $node_link->{a} }->{ $node_link->{$b} } = 1;
    $clusters{ $node_link->{b} } ||= {};
    $clusters{ $node_link->{b} }->{ $node_link->{$a} } = 1;
}

my @clusters;

while (my($node, $node_links) = each %clusters) {
    my %cluster;
    $cluster{$node} = 1;
    delete $clusters{$node};
    build_cluster(\%clusters, \%cluster, $node_links);
    push(@clusters, \%cluster);
}

sub build_cluster {
    my($clusters, $cluster, $node_links) = @_;

    for my $node (keys %$node_links) {
        $cluster->{$node} = 1;
        if ($clusters->{$node}) {
            my $next_node_links = delete $clusters->{$node};
            build_cluster($clusters, $cluster, $next_node_links);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I load the nodes from a file, let s say file.dat?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions presented here, you can also solve this problem with [Graph::UnionFind](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/Graph-0.94/lib/Graph/UnionFind.pm). I think it may help to point you to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235301/how-can-i-create-unique-sets-given-a-list-of-pairwise-relationships-with-perl) I asked recently because it offers good solutions to the same problem.